# Click accepting everywhere on a section to open and close section

Tags: swift, swiftui, sections, modifier

For macOS I use the

```
.contentShape(Rectangle())
```

modifier on other items like the TabBar to make the whole view accepting the click.
However I can't get that to work in the section of a list. I don't know how to extend the open and close icon view to accept click to the whole section; not only the text but also the empty space between the text and icon. I use modifiers extensions to create my own modifiers. Here I got just two samples. but how can I reach the whole section?

```
import SwiftUI

struct Label_Extension: View {
    var body: some View {
        List() {
            Label("Bikes and Prices", systemImage: "banknote")
                .labelStyle(.tabBarTag)
        }
        List {
            Section (header: Label("Bikes and Prices", systemImage: "banknote")
                .labelStyle(.sideBarSection)) {
                    Text("Buy and Sell")
                    Label("Bikes and Prices", systemImage: "banknote")
                        .labelStyle(.sideBarSection)
                }
        }.listStyle(.sidebar)
    }
}


extension LabelStyle where Self == SideBarSectionLabelStyle {
    static var sideBarSection: SideBarSectionLabelStyle {
        SideBarSectionLabelStyle()
    }
}

extension LabelStyle where Self == TabBarTagLabelStyle {
    static var tabBarTag: TabBarTagLabelStyle {
        TabBarTagLabelStyle()
    }
}

struct TabBarTagLabelStyle: LabelStyle {
    private var iconWidth = 14.0
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        HStack {
            configuration.icon
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                .frame(width: iconWidth)
            configuration.title
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
        }
        .padding(8)
        .background(in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5, style: .continuous))
        .compositingGroup()
        .font(.caption)
    }
}

struct SideBarSectionLabelStyle: LabelStyle {
    private var iconWidth = 18.0
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        HStack {
            configuration.icon
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .frame(width: iconWidth)
            configuration.title
                .foregroundColor(.red)
        }
        .padding(6)
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .font(.title2)
    }
}

#Preview {
    Label_Extension()
}
```

How can I solve this? What do I miss.

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't see anything that can expand or collapse in your code. Can you show some screenshots of the collapsed section, highlight the area in which you want to detect touches, and another screenshot that shows the expanded section.

Comment: I will make them; just started cooking. In the meantime (or is it meanTime ); the section header shows at the end a triangle to open and close a list section and show the items. But it opens and closes just when the user clicks on that triangle.

Comment: added the images

Comment: Of the lack of comment i suppose this cant be possible?